# How can I execute linux command inside EC2 using AWS CLI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have some EC2 instances running on AWS. I am able to get the instance details and start and stop the instance using the AWS CLI command. I was looking for a way to execute a few Linux commands inside the AWS EC2 instances using CLI.

Actually, I am creating a Jenkins pipeline which stops and starts the EC2 instance using AWS CLI. But I also need to execute a few commands after the EC2 is started.

I tried using the `aws ssm send-command` but it seems this command is not working for me. I tried the below example command and got the error.

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --instance-ids "instance-ID" \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --comment "IP config" \
    --parameters commands=ifconfig \
    --output text
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances [[i-xxxx]] not in a valid state for account XXXXXXXX
```

Is there any alternate approach to executing commands using AWS CLI?

Comment: Are those instances in running state?

Comment: @jarmod yes, the instance is in running state and I am able to SSH and execute commands manually

Comment: @DeepakKumar, can you check your instance state via cli? Sometimes console gives you wrong state. (aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id $instance-ID)

Comment: @Riz I even tried using the CLI instance status and getting status as running and status code as 16

Comment: Your region and account are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is your EC2 instance viewable in Systems Manager? You won't be able to use `aws ssm send-command` if your EC2 instance can't talk to Systems Manager.

Make sure your EC2 instance has the following roles:

- AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`

Make sure you EC2 can access the following internet domains (or VPC endpoints):

- ssm.[region].amazonaws.com
- ec2messages.[region].amazonaws.com
- ssmmessages.[region].amazonaws.com